# ControlValueAccessor component not updating value in formgroup at angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm using angular 7. And I created child component like below Stackblitz by `ControlValueAccessor`. I have a combobox and textbox in my form. And when I select item from combobox, then value of item set to textbox. But when I clicked "SAVE" button, my form value coming as empty. What can be the reason of coming as empty?

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-5fwery?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-child-component%2Fmy-child-component.component.ts)

Comment: the onChange you're calling in your template is doing .... nothing ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 2 changes to make it work.

First of all your `onChange()` method does nothing.

Change it to `public onChange: (value) => void`.

Then call `this.onChange(selected)` on your `set selectedItem(selected)` after writing to the  `value` property so it becomes

```
set selectedItem(selected) {
    this.value = selected;
    this.onChange(selected);
}
```

See [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-mupyjy?file=src/app/my-child-component/my-child-component.component.ts)

Comment: Not sure this question will help anybody on earth someday but you'll get easy reputation points ^^ (oh you deleted it xD)